# Azure function running when not scheduled too

Tags: azure, timer, azure-functions

I have an Azure function scheduled to run at 59 minutes past the hour */59 * * * *.  However whilst it runs at 59 minutes it also runs at 00.  I have set the RunOnStartup to false but this is still occurring, does anyone have an idea as to why this is and what can be done to resolve this that they can share with me please?

Logs from Azure:
[image]

Comment: After looking online I think the answer maybe setting the cron job as 59 * * * * rather than */59 * * * *.  Will test and see if this works.

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks.

Comment: It works fine as 59 * * * *, ostensibly I have removed the second portion and this is running exactly as I wished.

Comment: That's weird. We never success with 5 field:(.

Answer (score 0):

The [cron expression for azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-expressions) includes sixth field: `{second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day-of-week}`.

If you want it to run at 59minutes each hour, you should specify it as `* 59 * * * *`.